# Why does the text in ListView item disappear when scrolling?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have `ListView` which contains items containing a `View` and a `TextView`:

chat_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="90dp"
 android:id="@+id/chat_message_wrapper"
 xmlns:pixlui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.neopixl.pixlui">

<View
    android:id="@+id/message_indicator"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"/>

<com.neopixl.pixlui.components.textview.TextView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/midnight_blue"
    android:padding="14dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is `getView()` in my Adapter class:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_item, null);
        }

        ChatMessageItem item = getItem(position);
        if(item != null) {
            TextView messageTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);

            ViewGroup messageWrapper = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.chat_message_wrapper);
            View messageIndicatorView = view.findViewById(R.id.message_indicator);

            if(messageTextView != null) {
                messageTextView.setText(String.valueOf(item.getMessage()));
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)messageTextView.getLayoutParams();
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams indicatorParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(10, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams messageWrapperParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 90);
                if(item.getSender() == ChatMessageItem.Sender.ME) {

                    textParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.message_indicator);
                    indicatorParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                    messageIndicatorView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.light_blue));

                }
                else if(item.getSender() == ChatMessageItem.Sender.OTHER) {
                    textParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.message);
                    indicatorParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                    messageIndicatorView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.silver));
                }

                messageTextView.setLayoutParams(textParams);
                messageIndicatorView.setLayoutParams(indicatorParams);
                messageWrapper.setLayoutParams(messageWrapperParams);



            }
        }
        return view;
    }
```

I added the following line to at least keep the height of the items constant, which used to also change (which will probably give me problems later, as the content is dynamic, but ok..)

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams messageWrapperParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 90);
```

The problem is when I scroll up and down more and more text disappears. `messageIndicatorView` does not disappear though, only the text disappears. If I keep scrolling enough, all text will disappear. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks. (I know I must use a ViewHolder for better performance, but I will do that when this problem is fixed)

Comment: it is not related but 90 in layoutparams constructor does not same meaning in xml 90dp. dp can refer different px (it is type of layoutparams) on different devices. I think you should try without setting layoutparams to messageWrapper view

Comment: @Adem If I remove that line, the height of the items will also change randomly when I'm scrolling through the list. Apparently it's not the same as setting it in the xml file in this case.

Comment: so, it would be good idea to change message's height from wrap_content to match_parent. and use indicatorParams from  indicator. dont create new layoutparams

Comment: @Adem Yes, that would be better, I think I even tried that. But I will optimize this when I fix the main problem. Thanks.

Comment: it might be because of custom text object. so set a background to message object. and also use textParams.addRule(RelativeLayout. ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

Comment: @Adem I have no problem with positioning or the textview being custom, I don't think that is the problem. Why would I use ALIGN_PARENT_TOP? My text shows perfectly, the problem is only when I scroll.

Comment: bacuase, even, I dont know the custom textview code, code seems fine. there can be two possible things. one, object itself can be moved when you scroll the listview. or, text inside of textview is moving. for instance, text can be moved if custom textview also captures touch events and process them (it seems non sense, but it is possible).

Comment: Instead of using the LayourParams with which the messageTextView comes try creating new LayoutParams for it. As you don't use two types of rows those LayourParams will get wrong rules when the view is recycled in another type of message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that as the ListView recycles and reuses the views, conflicting rules are added to the `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` instances for the `@id/message` TextView. In particular this happens whenever a view for a "ME" message is reused for an "OTHER" message, or vice-versa.

`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` keeps a list of rules (actually an array by verb, so that you cannot add, say, two `LEFT_OF` rules -- but any other combination is possible, including problematic ones).

The easiest solution is to use a new `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` object each time, by changing this line:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textParams = 
    (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)messageTextView.getLayoutParams();
```

into:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textParams = 
    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

There are other solutions, such as having different actual layouts for each kind of ListView item (via [`getItemViewType()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29)) but it's probably overkill in this case. However if the differences between the two kinds of views were greater, it might be worth considering.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I get this ClassCastException: "android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams". Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: @Loolooii If you added the `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams messageWrapperParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 90)` line, then remove it. The message_wrapper view will not be contained inside a RelativeLayout, but inside the ListView itself.

Comment: Thanks! The disappearing problem of the text is now solved, however the message_indicator view does not show now! That's why in the first place I added the line you told me to remove. Do you know what I should do?

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem by removing MATCH_PARENT from height paramter of indicatorParams and use a number. I have to wait 20 hours to give you the bounty :)

Comment: @Loolooii glad to have helped! :-)